# Testing scrollintoview while unit testing angular

Tags: angular, testing, scroll, scrollview, karma-runner

When unit testing a scrollintoview() method in Angular 2+, I receive an error -> *"Failed: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined" in Angular 2+*

Here is my scrollintoview code:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this trough an execute script?

Comment: This happens because in unit test `document` object isn't create so you invoke `scrollIntoView` method on undefined element.  You can test this and add `console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('class') );` before this and start unit test. In console look for result and it's your solution.

Answer (score 5):

*Probably one year too late to answer this.*

This is one of the solutions for testing `document.getElementsByClassName('someDiv')[0].scrollIntoView({...})`

You could create a `spyOn`

```
spyOn(document.getElementsByClassName('someDiv')[0], 'scrollIntoView').and.callThrough();
```

And then expect scrollIntoView to have been called

```
expect(document.getElementsByClassName('someDiv')[0].scrollIntoView).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

To ensure that your `document.getElementsByClassName('someDiv')[0]` in not undefined add an extra expect:

```
expect(document.getElementsByClassName('someDiv')[0]).not.toBeDefined();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have tried this approach

1. I have defined the element I want to scroll into

```html
   

 <div #highlightsContainer>... </div>
```

2. I have defined a viewChild in my component and the method I used to scroll

```js
@ViewChild('highlightsContainer') highlightsContainer;  


scrollToHighlightsContainer() {
       setTimeout(() => { this.highlightsContainer.nativeElement.scrollIntoView(true)});
}
```

2. Then in my test

```js
  it('should scroll', fakeAsync(() => {
      component.highlightsContainer.nativeElement.scrollIntoView = jest.fn();
      component.scrollToHighlightsContainer();
      tick();
      expect(component.highlightsContainer.nativeElement.scrollIntoView)
        .toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```